# Add lines of a txt to a list

Tags: python

Say i've got a text file which contains the lines:

```
ABCD

E  F

GHIJ
```

How would I add each line into an empty list so the list would be:

```
ls = ["ABCD", "E  F", "GHIJ"]
```

The spaces between E and F are included